# Extract all conditions from Expression by Type

Tags: c#, lambda, expression, expression-trees, expressionvisitor

Given an `Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>` along the lines of

```
entity => entity.SubEntity.Any(
    subEntity => (
        (subEntity.SomeProperty == False)
        AndAlso
        subEntity.SubSubEntity.FooProperty.StartsWith(
            value(SomeClass+<>c__DisplayClass0).ComparisonProperty
        )
        AndAlso
        subEntity.SubSubEntity.BarProperty == "Bar"
        AndAlso
        subEntity.SubSubEntity.SubSubSubEntity.Any(
            subSubSubEntity => (x.SubSubSubSubEntity.BazProperty == "whatever")
        )
    )
)
```

I am trying to extract a list property conditions by type, i.e.

```
TEntity             : [ /* no conditions for immediate members of TEntity */ ] 
TSubEntity          : [ { SomeProperty == False } ]
TSubSubEntity       : [ { FooProperty.StartsWith(/* ... */) },
                        { BarProperty == "Bar" } ],
TSubSubSubEntity    : [ /* no conditions for immediate members of TSubSubSubEntity */ ],
TSubSubSubSubEntity : [ { BazProperty == "whatever" } ]
```

So far, I have created an `ExpressionVisitor` and identified the `VisitBinary` method as the one I want to plug into in order to obtain my information.

I am still at a loss about

- how to determine whether the `BinaryExpression` I am looking at represents a terminal statement (in the sense that there are no more nested expressions that I need to look at)
- how to determine the Entity type that the `BinaryExpression` is concerned with
- whether I need to override any of the other `ExpressionVisitor` methods to cover for cases that I have not considered yet.

Comment: Can you post the `ExpressionVisitor` code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what really is the use case, but here is some starting point

```
class TestVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    public Dictionary<Type, List<Tuple<MemberExpression, Expression>>> Result = new Dictionary<Type, List<Tuple<MemberExpression, Expression>>>();
    Stack<Expression> stack = new Stack<Expression>();
    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        stack.Push(node);
        base.Visit(node);
        stack.Pop();
        return node;
    }
    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        if (node.Expression.NodeType != ExpressionType.Constant && (node.Type == typeof(string) || !typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(node.Type)))
        {
            var expression = stack.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
            if (expression != null && expression.Type == typeof(bool))
            {
                List<Tuple<MemberExpression, Expression>> resultList;
                if (!Result.TryGetValue(node.Expression.Type, out resultList))
                    Result.Add(node.Expression.Type, resultList = new List<Tuple<MemberExpression, Expression>>());
                resultList.Add(Tuple.Create(node, expression));
            }
        }
        return base.VisitMember(node);
    }
}
```

The idea is simple. Override `Visit` method just to maintain a stack of processing expressions. The main processing is inside the `VisitMember` override, which is called for each property/field accessor. The `node.Expression.NodeType != ExpressionType.Constant` is used to eliminate the closure members, while the second condition eliminates collection properties. Finally, the potential condition expression is extracted from the stack.

The result is including both `MemberExpression` and the `Expression` where it is used. `MemberExpression.Expression.Type` is your entity type, `MemberExpression.Member` is the property/field of that type.

Sample test:

```
class Entity
{
    public ICollection<SubEntity> SubEntity { get; set; }
}

class SubEntity
{
    public bool SomeProperty { get; set; }
    public SubSubEntity SubSubEntity { get; set; }
}

class SubSubEntity
{
    public string FooProperty { get; set; }
    public string BarProperty { get; set; }
    public ICollection<SubSubSubEntity> SubSubSubEntity { get; set; }
}

class SubSubSubEntity
{
    public SubSubSubSubEntity SubSubSubSubEntity { get; set; }
}

class SubSubSubSubEntity
{
    public string BazProperty { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string comparisonProperty = "Ivan";
        Expression<Func<Entity, bool>> e =
            entity => entity.SubEntity.Any(subEntity =>
                subEntity.SomeProperty == false
                &&
                subEntity.SubSubEntity.FooProperty.StartsWith(comparisonProperty)
                &&
                subEntity.SubSubEntity.BarProperty == "Bar"
                &&
                subEntity.SubSubEntity.SubSubSubEntity.Any(subSubSubEntity => subSubSubEntity.SubSubSubSubEntity.BazProperty == "whatever")
                );
        var v = new TestVisitor();
        v.Visit(e);
        var result = v.Result;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is a very interesting idea!!!
unfortunately there are way too many corner cases, that you will only be discovering on the way, as bugs. for example t.BoolProp == true && t.BoolProp mean the same, but are represented quite differently. What about t.CollectionProp.Any(), t.CollectionProp.FirstOrDefault() != null, etc etc etc....
This problem gets very compilcated really soon!!! and im quite sure that in some cases it is not even clear how to proceed. But +1 for the stack